# React/Redux search filter update app state as you type

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a search filter where the app state gets updated as you type your search query in the input field. So far in my component, I'm being able to view the initial app state.

In my reducer I'm doing a check to see if the search query matches any of the animals - and then i update the app state accordingly (by filtering out the unmatched objects). The checking seems to be working fine but its not rendering to screen.

EDIT:
It now narrows down the search by updating the state BUT i need a way to go back up the app state as I delete characters from the search field. Any idea how?

Action creator:

```
export const FETCH_DATA = 'FETCH_DATA'
export function search(data){
    return {
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: data
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/index';
var _ = require('lodash');

const initialState = [
      {
        "animal": "Heron, giant"
      }, {
        "animal": "Lizard"
      }, {
        "animal": "Blesbok"
      }, {
        "animal": "Ibex"
      }, {
        "animal": "Pigeon, wood"
      }, {
        "animal": "Ground monitor"
      }
]

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_DATA:
        const {payload} = action
            state = _.filter(state, function(o){
              return o.animal.toLowerCase().includes(payload.toLowerCase());
            })
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

CombineReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SearchReducer from './reducer_search';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  animals: SearchReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {search} from '../actions/index';

class Search extends Component {
    render() {
        //console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> this.props.search(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div>
//conditional rendering
                    <ul>
                    {
                        this.props.data.filtered.length == 0 ? 
                        this.props.data.animals.map(item => {
                            return <li>{item.animal}</li>
                        }) :
                        this.props.data.filtered.map(item => {
                            return <li>{item.animal}</li>
                        })
                    }
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {data : state.animals}
}

//action creator
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({search}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

Comment: Save the filter query inside your store or inside your component state and do the filtering inside the render method.

Comment: @trixn then what should be inside the Reducer?

Comment: This problem does not need redux at all. But if you really want to store the filter query inside the redux store the reducer will just update the filter query which you will map to your component. The way you implemented it you will wipe your entire store on the first user input.

Comment: I realise now how it will wipe the entire store on user input. Can you tell me how to retain the previous state of the store in my reducer?

Comment: And on which action would you want to retain which previous state?
Retaining the previous state would require to store the old state somewhere. You should see your animals data as your data basis which should not be removed from the store at any time other than when you want the animal entirely to be removed forever. If this is some kind of an exercise  to practice redux you could build a second list of filtered animals that you update according to your query string and map that to your component.

Comment: You can find the tutorial on building search filter here 
 but without redux - https://youtu.be/RM_nXOyHwN0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) excludes anything that does not return `true`.

Given your current implementation: if you tried to search `"Lizard"`; your entire `state` would be wiped at `"L"` as `'L' === o.animal` would return `false` in all cases.

I would recommend using [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) rather than entirely strict comparing using `===`.

It would also be more robust to `filter()` within your `render()` method. Currently, if things don't match, they are thrown away entirely.

See below for an example.

```js
class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      animals: [
        {
          animal: 'Heron, giant'
        }, {
          animal: 'Lizard'
        }, {
          animal: 'Blesbok'
        }, {
          animal: 'Ibex'
        }, {
          animal: 'Pigeon, wood'
        }, {
          animal: 'Ground monitor'
        }
      ],
      query: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
     <div>

       <div>
         <input placeholder="search" value={this.state.query || ''} onChange={(event) => this.setState({query: event.target.value})}/>
       </div>
       
       <br/>

       <div>
         <div>ANIMALS</div>
         {this.state.animals.filter((animal) => _.toLower(animal.animal).includes(_.toLower(this.state.query || ''))).map((animal) => <div>{animal.animal}</div>)}
       </div>

     </div>

    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Search/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Redux Solution:

```
// Dependencies.
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/index' // Actions.
const _ = require('lodash') // Lodash.

const animals = [
  {
    "animal": "Heron, giant"
  }, {
    "animal": "Lizard"
  }, {
    "animal": "Blesbok"
  }, {
    "animal": "Ibex"
  }, {
    "animal": "Pigeon, wood"
  }, {
    "animal": "Ground monitor"
  }
]

// Initial State.
const initialState = {
  animals,
  filtered: animals
}

// Reducer.
export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case FETCH_DATA:
      const {payload} = action
      const filtered = _.filter(state.animals, (o) => _.toLower(o.animal).includes(_.toLower(payload)))
      return {...state, filtered}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a Redux implementation of the problem. The way you did it uses only React.

Comment: Yes mate. The `filter()` and `includes()` strategies I outlined can be pasted to your `Redux` `action`. The example was to prove they work.

Comment: The solution to your time travel problem is to keep the `query` and `animals` data separate.

Comment: Keep your `animals` `array` in your `store` and don't touch it. Have another `array` called `results`. Every time input is provided: `filter()` your `animals` `array` and save it to `results`. 100% Redux.

Comment: i tried storing the filtered array in a new variable in my reducer but it didn't change anything. can you please show me this redux implementation?

Comment: All good. I've appended an example to my answer. Paste that over your `reducer` file and reference `this.props.filtered` from your `component` for the `filtered` `array`.

Comment: Makes total sense! I was actually thinking in that line when you made that update to your post. Please check my updated component - i do a conditional rendering based on whether filtered array is empty or not. Let me know if its the right way or not. It seems to work.

Comment: You could optimize your implementation by omitting the first check and instead setting the `initial value` of `filtered` to equal `animals` within your `store`. I've revised my solution to demonstrate this.

Comment: I'm Aussie by the way. If your firm is looking to contract any ReactJS devs.